# embed responsive pdf or svg in html

Tags: html, pdf, svg

I have some charts in pdf format using truetype fonts and "vector" images - the file sizes are typically 30kb. I have also converted these pdf files to svg using Inkscape and optimized using svgo - the file sizes are typically 100kb.

These pdf and svg files scale "responsively" in the devices I have checked as well as using OperaMobileEmulator and Firefox Responsive Design Mode.

I would prefer that the user loads the pdf file which is 30% the size of the svg and since not all browsers support embedded pdf - I use a "fallback" to svg - here is the relevant markup:

```
       <style>
       object {height:60em; width:100%}
       img {height:100%; width:100%}
       </style>

       <object data="7x7.pdf" type="application/pdf" >
       <img src="7x7.svgo.svg" alt="">
       </object>
```

Does the overhead for a pdf "plugin" make it less efficient than loading the svg?

TIA

EDIT
Here is some more information. I am using svgo to optimize.
I am using an unique truetype font [starfisher.ttf]. I did create webfonts:

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'starfisherregular';
    src: url('starfisher-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('starfisher-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    }
```

which works for displaying text, but in my charts, I am using starfisher glyphs. I have been unable to use font-family to generate these glyphs, I even tried using starfisher svg font in font-face which did not work and was unsuccessful in trying to add this font to svg defs - so I have to convert the text to paths when I open my pdf in inkscape using poppler - hence my svg file is larger than my pdf file. I can save this as Compressed Plain SVG - but I can't get it to display in my browsers.

My .htaccess file is:

```
AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz
```

My markup is:

```
    <object type="image/svg+xml svgz" data="7x7.svgz">
    Your browser does not support SVG
    </object>
```

All I get is "Your browser does not support SVG"

Answer (score 0):

You SVGs may have a lot of unnecessary Inskcape data in them. Try saving from Inkscape as "Plain SVG" or "Optimized SVG".  You should also consider serving the SVGs as `.svgz` (gzipped SVGs).  Save from Inkscape as "Compressed Plain SVG".